# decoding json and insert to db in php

Tags: c#, php, json

I have an exe app which is written in WPF C#.

and I want to pass to site in php data, and 
this data I want to passed into the db.

the web service is written in a php.

how can I do this php code? also not sure about my C#...

here is the c# code:

```
 public static void AddNewUserArrayJson(List<UsersExcelInfo> LUEI)
    {
        string ParameterURL = "?Action=AddNewUserArray";
        string URL = CConsts.BASE_URL + ParameterURL;



        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(LUEI);            
         var httpContent = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
        {

            // Do the actual request and await the response
            var httpResponse =  httpClient.PostAsync(URL, httpContent)               
        }

    }
```

and here is the php code I tried to write

```
if ($Action=="AddNewUserArray")
{       
    $_POST = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
    $id =  explode(",",$_POST['id']);
    $FirstName =  explode(",",$_POST['FirstName']);
    $LastName =  explode(",",$_POST['LastName']);
    $Phone = explode(",", $_POST['Phone']);
    $TypeOfUser =  explode(",",$_POST['TypeOfUser']);
    $Gender =  explode(",",$_POST['Gender']);
    $ExpiredDate =  explode(",",$_POST['ExpiredDate']);
    $Favor =  explode(",",$_POST['Favor']);
    $Remarks = explode(",", $_POST['Remarks']);
    $Email = explode(",", $_POST['Email']);
    $DateOfBirth =  explode(",",$_POST['DateOfBirth']);
    $RegestraionDancer = explode(",", $_POST['RegestraionDancer']);     

    $length = count($id);
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) 
    {
        $query="INSERT INTO `Users` (`id`, `FirstName`, `LastName`, `Phone`, `TypeOfUser`, `Gender`, `ExpiredDate`, `Favor`, `Remarks`, `Email`, `DateOfBirth`, `RegestraionDancer`) VALUES ('$id[$i]', '$FirstName[$i]', '$LastName[$i]', '$Phone[$i]', '$TypeOfUser[$i]', '$Gender[$i]', '$ExpiredDate[$i]', '$Favor[$i]', '$Remarks[$i]', '$Email[$i]', '$DateOfBirth[$i]', '$RegestraionDancer[$i]')";          
        $result = mysqli_query($mysqli,$query);
    }               
}
```

would be happy for some help...